# ggnetwork data import format

Tags: r, ggnetwork

I can't for the life of me figure out how to structure my data for use in ggnetwork.

I have a separate program that can generate structured data in any format i choose. Given that ggnetwork data can be

- data that infers a link between one node and another (adjacency style)
- data that adds an attribute/value to an edge
- data that adds an attribute/value to a node

How can i import these? Let's go one at a time here--

#### Adjancency Data

This part i got-- i just create a matrix via code like

```
data <- matrix(c(1,0,3,0,5,6,1,2,3), nrow=3)
colnames(data)=rownames(data)=LETTERS[1:3]

net <- network(data, matrix.type="adjacency")
```

Doable. Straightforward.

#### Node Attributes

In [the example here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggnetwork/vignettes/ggnetwork.html) i see this code:

```
n <- network(rgraph(10, tprob = 0.2), directed = FALSE)
n %v% "family" <- sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE)
n %v% "importance" <- sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE)
```

I have no idea what the `n %v%` does, but i'd like to be able to do a dump of `node id, attribute val` and just import that in to my nodes.

#### Edge Values

Again, in the example i see

```
e <- network.edgecount(n)
set.edge.attribute(n, "type", sample(letters[24:26], e, replace = TRUE))
set.edge.attribute(n, "day", sample(1:3, e, replace = TRUE))
```

But i don't know what that means, or how i can add this data via appending it to my adjacency list, since that is already 1-1 data mapping to edges.

*How can I make an import for my edges with their vals, and an import for my nodes vals?*

Comment: According to network package documentation, **The %n% and %v% operators serve as front-ends to the network and vertex extraction/assignment functions
(respectively).**

Comment: Could you explain your adjaceny matrix (beause some terms are not 0 or 1) ? Could you add some data sample ?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington i'm working under the assumption that that is the edge values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
(1,0,3,0,5,6,1,2,3)
```

Are your imorted values, you can try this :

```
imported_values <-  c(1,0,3,0,5,6,1,2,3)
data <- matrix(imported_values, nrow=3)
colnames(data)=rownames(data)=LETTERS[1:3]
net <- network(data, matrix.type="adjacency")
net %v% "importance" <- imported_values
ggplot(net, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_edges() +
  geom_nodes(aes(size = importance)) +
  theme_blank()
```